# Gradle generate custom test report

Tags: gradle, test-reporting

I need a bit of help building custom test reports.

Each test would have an output like 'result x', 'result y' which would then be stored in either 1 global report file or 1 report per test.

A naive approach would be to use the 'tear down' part of each test to append the info in a global file.

The output file shouldn't interfere with junit, jacoco or other reports.

Can this be achieved by doing a custom gradle plugin or reusing some functionality in other plugins?

Thank you

Comment: Generating HTML reports for your tests via Gradle: https://medium.com/@ishabbi/generating-html-reports-for-your-test-runs-via-gradle-the-easy-way-aa4d8860d18c

Answer (score 0):

The gradle [Test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html) task supports custom [TestListener](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestListener.html)s. There's also convenience methods for [beforeTest](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:beforeTest%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) and [afterTest](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:afterTest%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)

eg:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
test {
    afterTest { TestDescriptor td, TestResult tr ->
        writeToSomeFile(td.className, td.name, tr.resultType.name())
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Is there any way to interact with the TestListener from the unit test? That's the only place in which I have all the info I need. Thank you

Comment: No, it can't. Perhaps you want a custom junit [Rule](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Rule.html)